# How can I delete the last line of a text file using the command prompt?

Tags: cmd

I have a text file that I am importing into access table using command prompt. The problem is that this text file has a blank line as the last line. Can anyone provide me with a script that deletes my blank line at the end of file so as I can finalize my automation process. I am using Windows 2000 platform.

Comment: Samar, are you going to ask another question about deleting other empty lines in the file?

Answer (score 4):

```
 sed "$d" input.txt > output.txt
```

deletes the last line, but it's not provided by Windows (2000, XP, 7). Get the gnu utils to obtain a sed for Windows.

On [this site](http://student.northpark.edu/pemente/sed/sed1line.txt) you will find a list of other sed commands to manipulate files.

Answer (score 3):

This works using `head`

```
head -n -1 input.txt > output.txt
```

Unfortunately I think Windows doesn't come with that useful tool by default, but installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) gives you that and a lot of other stuff as well.

Comment: You might try looking here for Windows ports of Unix utilities: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/jan06/hey0103.mspx) is a script that deletes blank lines from a text file. It is written for windows 2000.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\Test.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.Readline
    strLine = Trim(strLine)
    If Len(strLine) > 0 Then
        strNewContents = strNewContents & strLine & vbCrLf
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\Test.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.Write strNewContents
objFile.Close
```

Comment: come on now, don't you see this can be done in 1 line with the right tool?

Comment: Yup, or you can simply use this script without an additional tool to worry about. Its old tech, but it works. He asked for win2k otherwise I would have used PowerShell.

Comment: (get-content C:\File.txt) | where {$_ -ne ""} | out-file c:\file.txt

Comment: 1. This script removes all blank lines, but the requirement was to only delete the last blank line.
2. This script also removes leading and trailing spaces.
3. This script loads the entire file into memory and performs a lot of string appends while building the result string.